# Checkboxes are not appearing in inline

Tags: html

I'm struggling with checkboxes. I want to display them on one line next to each other. Here's my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q2q54jz2/).

**HTML**

```
<form style="height:1200px;"role="form" method="post" action="../process.php">
    <label>Your Name*</label>
    <input name="name" placeholder="">

    <label>Email Address*</label>
    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="">
        Your approximately budget for website
    <input name="budget" placeholder="">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>What is Your Favorite Pet?</legend>

        <input type="checkbox" name="animal" value="Cat" /><p style=" margin-right:200px;">Cats </p><br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="animal" value="Dog" />Dogs<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="animal" value="Bird" />Birds<br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit now" />
    </fieldset>     
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
form {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width: 343px;
    height: 333px;
    padding:30px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    background: linear-gradient(top,rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 30%,rgba(0,0,0,.3) 60%);
    box-shadow: 0 0 13px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    overflow: hidden; 
}

textarea{
      background: rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.3) url(http://estudio87.com/img/gemicon_message.png) no-repeat scroll 16px 16px; 
    width: 276px;
    height: 110px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.6);
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box; 
    display:block;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size:18px;
    color:#fff;
    padding-left:45px;
    padding-right:20px;
    padding-top:12px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

input {
    width: 276px;
    height: 48px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.4);
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box; 
    display:block;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size:18px;
    color:#fff;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

input[type=submit] {
    cursor:pointer;
}

input.name {
    background: rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.3) url(http://estudio87.com/img/gemicon_name.png) no-repeat scroll 16px 16px; 
    padding-left:45px;
}

input.email {
    background: rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.3) url(http://estudio87.com/img/gemicon_email.png) no-repeat scroll 16px 20px;
    padding-left:45px;
}

input.message {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) url(http://estudio87.com/img/gemicon_message.png) no-repeat scroll 16px 16px;
    padding-left:45px;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #fff;
}

:-moz-placeholder{ 
    color: #fff; 
}

::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #fff;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
    color: #fff; 
}

input:focus, textarea:focus { 
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Please place the relevant code in the question to avoid link rot.

Comment: http://www.jsfiddle.net/q2q54jz2/

Answer (score 0):

According to you code below each checkbox you have an 
 tag which prevent the checkbox element to display in one line,  second wrap each of checkboxes with its label into a div and add it a class like **custom-checkbox** and style it like: **display inline-block** like folow:

```
<div class="custom-checkbox">
 <input type="checkbox" name="animal" value="Cat" /><label>Checkbox 1</label>
</div>
```

Hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of sounding condescending (not my intention): You have such an abundance of explicit line breaks that one might be led to believe you are [trolololing](http://youtu.be/2Z4m4lnjxkY).

1. You are forcing a [line break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) after each checkbox with the `<br />` tag. If you don't want to have a line break, then remove the `<br />` tag.
2. The `<p>` tag is not an appropriate replacement for a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label). Most browsers style the `<p>` tag with `display: block` (which forces the following element to start on a new line), because this tag semantically represents a paragraph. If you want to style the checkbox text, then wrap it in a "unsemantic" [span](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) instead.
3. As mentioned in the previous point, `display: block` forces the following element to start on a new line. You are adding this style to *all* input elements in your CSS with `input { display:block; }`. I am not sure why you are doing this, but I would suggest using a class instead to make the selector more specific.
4. You are setting an explicit width on *all* input elements with `input { width: 276px; }`. This leaves no room for the label text of the checkboxes in the `fieldset`, so the text is pushed to the next line.

As you did not provide an example image of how you want the form to look, I am not even going to attempt to provide additional code to resolve your issues. However, hopefully you are able to figure it out with the facts I have provided.

In conclusion, you should consider wrapping your checkboxes in a `label` element to allow the user to click the label text to select the associated checkbox:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="animal" value="Cat" /> Cats
</label>
```